# How does PHP zend.script_encoding work?

Tags: php, php-internals

I'm trying to get zend engine to interpret my PHP scripts as UTF-16BE. On a PHP 5.4 setup, I have the following settings in my PHP.ini file:

```
zend.script_encoding = UTF-16BE
zend.detect-unicode = 0
zend.multibyte = On
```

This is my script index.php:

```
<?php echo '1';
```

The file is a total of 32 bytes, saved using UTF-16BE:

```
FE FF // BOM
00 3C 00 3F 00 70 00 68 00 70 00 20 // <?php 
00 65 00 63 00 68 00 6F 00 20 // echo
00 27 00 31 00 27 // '1'
00 3B // ;
```

However the script is not working; the output is `<?php echo '1';` instead of `1`.

So I tried removing the BOM:

```
00 3C 00 3F 00 70 00 68 00 70 00 20 // <?php 
00 65 00 63 00 68 00 6F 00 20 // echo
00 27 00 31 00 27 // '1'
00 3B // ;
```

But the output is still `<?php echo '1';` instead of `1`.

Then I tried encoding the *start* sequence — `<?php`  — in ASCII, while the remaining characters remain UTF-16BE encoded:

```
3C 3F 70 68 70 20 // <?php 
00 65 00 63 00 68 00 6F 00 20 // echo
00 27 00 31 00 27 // '1'
00 3B // ;
```

The engine seems to be able to interpret the PHP script now, but it's still not working:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'c' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1

How does [`zend.script_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.script-encoding) work?

How can we get the engine to interpret scripts written in a specific encoding?

Comment: ***"When ISO-8859-1 imcompatible encoding is used, both zend.multibyte and zend.script_encoding must be used."*** - TFM

Comment: Any reason to do this? How about utf-8?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, Yes, I'm testing if the engine is working as expected. Throwing UTF-8 everywhere and anywhere such that things *seem* to work doesn't really mean things are closed to exploits.

Comment: @Pacerier: "Thanks it's working now" - "things seem to work doesn't really mean things are closed to exploits" :DDDD (note: no need to reply)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, Yea one step at a time. I'm getting alot of weird behavior here, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26585015/632951 . Perhaps we should blame it on the terseness of PHP docs.

Comment: @deceze, Btw, do you happen to know why the setting `detect-unicode` isn't working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585015/how-to-ensure-that-php-respects-zend-script-encoding-setting