# How to ensure that PHP respects zend.script_encoding setting?

Tags: php, encoding

On a PHP 5.4 setup, I have these settings in my PHP.ini:

```
zend.multibyte = On
zend.script_encoding = UTF-16BE
zend.detect-unicode = 0
```

I'm trying to get zend engine to interpret my PHP scripts in a specific encoding, e.g. UTF-16BE. This means that scripts encoded in another encoding should fail. **I do not want zend engine to do any guesswork at all**, regardless of the (in)existence of byte sequences like BOM marks.

This is my script index.php:

```
<?php echo '1';
```

The file is a total of 32 bytes, saved using UTF-16**LE**:

```
FF FE // BOM
3C 00 3F 00 70 00 68 00 70 00 20 00 // <?php
65 00 63 00 68 00 6F 00 20 00 // echo 
27 00 31 00 27 00 // '1'
3B 00 // ;
```

The script should fail, because the encoding provided is not UTF-16BE. However, the output is `1`, proving that the engine is doing encoding-guessing based on the supplied bytes.

The output is also `1` when we save the file using UTF-8 with BOM:

```
EF BB BF // BOM
3C 3F 70 68 70 20 // <?php
65 63 68 6F 20 // echo 
27 31 27 // '1'
3B // ;
```

Why is [`zend.detect-unicode`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.detect-unicode) not working as expected?

More importantly, How can we configure the engine to respect the supplied encoding in `zend.script_encoding`?

Comment: @NikiC, Why did you remove the "zend-engine" / "php-internals" tag when this question **is** about zend-engine?

Comment: This question (and all your other questions about zend multibyte support) is about how to use (or configure) PHP. I don't see how this relates to PHP internals. Unless you are interested in how exactly zend multibyte works from the implementational side (e.g. what the SCNG input and output filters are and how and when they are applied, how conversions are hooked / how it integrates with mbstring, how encodings are switched mid-lexing and why the implementation is total crap), then tagging as php-internals does not seem appropriate.

Comment: @NikiC, However this question is about the internal workings of zend-engine: an answer to this question would most likely reference the source code of Zend Engine showing why `zend.detect-unicode` is not working as expected, e.g. implementation bug.